# Android webview in marshmallow

Tags: android, webview

A recent update to Marshmallow has caused a problem with my app's WebView. My layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/errorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout is used in a dialog to show help, examples (the app is a calculator), and error messages:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + page);
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

This worked just fine in Lollipop but now just shows the button at the bottom of the layout instead of the entire content.  It acts like the view is being rendered before the loadUrl and sizing to an empty page.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

[Screen shot of dialog box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYYuA.png)

[Second screen shot shows dialog box after apps lost/returned focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYjT1.png)

Comment: Share the screen shot . So that it will be understandable .

Comment: Screen shots added